# How to run regression with multiple dependent variables and compare these models?

Tags: r, loops, variables, regression, purrr

Below, I manage to run regression with multiple dependent variables. How can I assign the results of these estimations to a model object inside the loop and then compare these models based on AIC/BIC measures using for instance `rcompanion::compareLM()`?

```
depvar <- c("qsec", "hp")
indepvar <- paste(c("mpg", "wt", "am", "disp"), collapse = " + ")

for(i in 1:length(depvar)){
  est_model <- lm(paste(depvar[i],"~", indepvar), data=mtcars)
  res <- summary(est_model)
  print(list(depvar[i], res))
}
```

Comment: Before the loop, `models <- list()`, inside the the loop `models[[i]] <- est_model`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `rcompanion`, but you could get all the AICs with `my_aic = sapply(models, AIC)`, but I like `broom`/`generics` packages for summarizing model results. If you load those and have `purrr` loaded you can `map_dfr(models, glance)` to get a data frame of model metrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
models <- list()
for(i in 1:length(depvar)){
  est_model <- lm(paste(depvar[i],"~", indepvar), data=mtcars)
  models[[i]] <- est_model
}

names(models) <- depvar
sapply(models, AIC)
#     qsec        hp 
# 97.38901 323.30591 

library(purrr)
library(broom)
map_dfr(models, glance, .id = "depvar")
# # A tibble: 2 × 13
#   depvar r.squared adj.r.sq…¹ sigma stati…² p.value    df logLik   AIC   BIC devia…³ df.re…⁴  nobs
#   <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <int> <int>
# 1 qsec       0.727      0.687  1.00    18.0 2.63e-7     4  -42.7  97.4  106.    27.0      27    32
# 2 hp         0.784      0.752 34.1     24.5 1.19e-8     4 -156.  323.   332. 31450.       27    32
# # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​adj.r.squared, ²​statistic, ³​deviance, ⁴​df.residual
```

Though I should warn that `AIC` and `BIC` aren't really appropriate  for comparing models with different responses.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of it, this was only for example purposes. Still thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

With `broom` you could go with something like this:

```r
library(broom)
library(purrr)

depvar <- c("qsec", "hp")
indepvar <- paste(c("mpg", "wt", "am", "disp"), collapse = " + ")

depvar |> 
  purrr::set_names() |>
  purrr::map(\(dep) lm(paste(dep,"~", indepvar), data=mtcars) |> broom::glance()) |> 
  list_rbind(names_to = "depvar")
#> # A tibble: 2 × 13
#>   depvar r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic      p.value    df logLik   AIC
#>   <chr>      <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 qsec       0.727         0.687  1.00      18.0 0.000000263      4  -42.7  97.4
#> 2 hp         0.784         0.752 34.1       24.5 0.0000000119     4 -156.  323. 
#> # ℹ 4 more variables: BIC <dbl>, deviance <dbl>, df.residual <int>, nobs <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>